# Qt QPainterpath.h errors

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, include-path, qpainter

I am currently working on a `Qt` application with many `#include` files from the `Qt` library.  The project is quite large and I have encountered a strange problem when building.  The errors displayed are all inside the `QPainterpath.h` file, but has nothing to do with calls to it from my project. The errors all look like this:

> c:\qt\4.8.4\include\qtgui../../src/gui/painting/qpainterpath.h(397) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '::'
>
> c:\qt\4.8.4\include\qtgui../../src/gui/painting/qpainterpath.h(397) : error C2059: syntax error : '::'
>
> c:\qt\4.8.4\include\qtgui../../src/gui/painting/qpainterpath.h(398) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
>
> c:\qt\4.8.4\include\qtgui../../src/gui/painting/qpainterpath.h(398) : error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
>
> c:\qt\4.8.4\include\qtgui../../src/gui/painting/qpainterpath.h(405) : warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'elementCount'

I encountered this once before and was able to solve it by moving some `Qt` #include statements called before other class headers below them. I can't seem to figure out what in particular is causing it this time though. Any thoughts would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen when you forget to close a class definition with a semicolon.  If you look at the output from the compiler, and see which file was compiled right before this error started, you may have your answer.  Look for syntax errors with missing a `;` or an extra `}` or a missing `}` at the end of the previously compiled file.

It could also be from a `.h` file listed above your `#include <QPainter>` call that has the errors.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That was initially my thought as well, but it happens after multiple .cpp files.  All of them have been thoroughly checked for missing braces and semicolons as well as the headers included in them.  My thought is that it has something to do with the Qt libraries disliking the order that they are being included in the file, but typically that shouldn't matter.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-In-Namespace could help if there are some weird circular dependencies.  Are you adding the right modules to your .pro file?  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-project-files.html#declaring-qt-libraries

Comment: So I checked the file before the errors were happening and found a GlobalData.h that was included before another class header. I added it after all of the other headers and it seems to work fine now.  I also went through and made sure I ordered each header by C++ headers, Qt headers, 3rd party headers, and our own class headers.  There were some discrepancies with calling classes instead of headers so thank you for that documentation.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with RyGuyFalcore and figured out why this is happening in our code, and nobody else is seeing it.  The issue is that our legacy code was redefining the elementCount macro.  Therefore, if we included that portion of our legacy code before we included the Qt code, the wrong macro was getting used :(  Figured I would post this here to avoid any wild goose chase that others may run into if they hit a similar bug.